# prowler for Azure - "There are no findings in Tenant ID/s <tenant ID>"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I run prowler for Azure, I get the following output:

"There are no findings in Tenant ID/s  "

I have provided the following API permissions added: Directory.Read.All and Policy.Read.All
I have the following RBAC roles added: Security Reader and Reader

Not sure why no data is coming back, I assumed it was a permissions issue, but I'm not sure. Can you assist?

[image]

I updated permissions, outside of that I'm not sure what else to do.